# PHP - how to work with long working operation

Tags: php

I have to update a lot of data in database. Operation needs approximately ~5min. I'm not PHP programmer and I don't know how to solve this problem (timeout on my server is set to 120ms). Currently I solved it in this way that I divided this operation in few smaller. This is not the best solution because I want to do it in one transaction. In more details this operation looks like this:

1. Take all product ids from application (~5000 ids).
2. Send those product ids via webservice to another server and wait for response.
3. Use data returned in response and update db with it (each product is updated separately because I want to use application API which isn't created by me).

Currently I divided it into steps. Each step sends 100ids. As I wrote I'm not happy with this solution because of no transaction.

These are requirements:

1. Operation can't be run through command line (application will run this operation as a request in cron).
2. Each product needs to be updated in separately because of build int API.
3. Because of transaction operation should be run in one step.

Capabilities:

1. Operation can be run asynchronous (if this is possible in php? - I don't know if I can install additional libraries which will handle this).

Comment: #1 cron indeed does run php over the command line, #2 that I cant help with. #3 are you saying "transaction" in the traditional term as it applies to a ACID complaint database, if so it invalidates #2, but I assume you are meaning one request / shot. #4 ( capabilities 1 ) cron indeed runs php asynchronously, as does the Apache server.  Are you sending to "another server" using post? if so you likly will be limited to 1000 inputs ( hashdos )

Answer (score 1):

If your safe mode is disabled, just add this to your script:

```
set_time_limit(10*60);
```

otherwise you can set the value in your php.ini

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: This could be a network timeout, "Send those product ids via webservice to another server and wait for response."